# Reduce reflections

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor, lighting

I've got a textured table with some objects placed on top. However, I'm unhappy with their reflections on the table surface: how can I reduce such reflections?

[image]

I'm using the following node setup for the table
(the solution shouldn't change the use of the Invert node)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I would try this:

1. Reduce specularity: this will make the reflections dimmer
2. Raise a bit the "roughness" zero-point: to do so, put a *Converter>ColorRamp* between your current *Roughness" input and the *Roughness* socket, and make the default black a bit less dark. This will make the reflections fuzzier

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Lower Principled shader's IOR value to 1.2, which will make reflections less distinct. Like more faded.